# Is it typical for residential buildings in Lima to require an ID card for visitors that enter the building even if accompanied by a building resident?

Tags: paperwork, accommodation, peru, lima

I read in my building regulation document for my apartment in [Miraflores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miraflores_District,_Lima), [Lima Province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima_Province) in Peru:

> By building regulations, if you are planning to receive a visitor into
> the apartment, please consider the following recommendations:
>
> - All visitors on arriving at the property, must register with the Front Desk (e.g., last-minute friend or pizza delivery).
> - Guests will be required to sign in their visitors at the Front Desk where they will provide visitor information stating their name,
>   apartment number and name of their visitor.
> - The Front Desk Agent will collect an **Identification card (Peruvian ID or Passport)** from the visitor which will be kept at the Front Desk
>   until the visitor is leaving. Please note that **a valid identification
>   card is required for each visitor for check-in/registration**.
> - On departure from the building, the visitor will return to the Front Desk where the agent will return their identification card.

Is it typical for  residential buildings in Lima to require an identification card for each visitor that enters the building, even when accompanied by a building resident? Or is that only common in upscale apartments in Miraflores? Or is that very unlikely / rare regardless of the location and building?

Comment: Does the building even _have_ a front desk?

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica yes

Comment: Interesting. The Building Regulations quoted say they're _recommendations_. Still,  I don't know the local customs and behavior.

Comment: How is this about travel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking only from personal experience, I would say that it is not *typical*. Yes, many high-rise buldings have front desk with some kind of security guard. Yes, they may ask you for indentification if you're visiting someone, but it didn't happen to me when I was visiting frineds and entering *with them*. However I can understand if they even want to identify *all* guests.

Also requirement to leave ID document at the desk seems little over-the-top. I used to carry photocopy of my passport for those purposes, when I needed to identify myself. I was never asked to leave my ID behind.